# Javascript Change an array to look in a particular format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that's displaying on a particular format and I need it modified so that it displays on another format.

Here is the code:

```
var arr = {
    "id":"100",
        "name":"the name",
        "places":[
    {
        "id":"23",
        "name":"first place",
        "startDate":"2015-01-30 15:01:00",
        "endDate":"2015-01-30 17:01:00"
    },

    {
        "id":"54",
        "name":"second place",
        "startDate":"2015-01-31 17:01:00",
        "endDate":"2015-02-01 17:01:00"

    },
    {
        "id":"400",
        "name":"third place",
        "startDate":"2015-02-01 17:01:00",
        "endDate":"2015-02-05 17:01:00"

    }

]

}

var phases = mainData.places.map(function(e){
   return e.name + "," + 50;
});

myvar = [ places ];
```

This is displaying the data like this:

```
["first place,50", "second place,50", "third place,50"]
```

But I need to data to be displayed like this:

```
[ ['first place', 50],['second place', 50],['third place', 50] ];
```

How can I change the code so that it displays in the wanted format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return the element as an array inside the **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method callback.

```
var phases = mainData.places.map(function(e){
   return [e.name , 50];
});
```

```js
var arr = {
  "id": "100",
  "name": "the name",
  "places": [{
    "id": "23",
    "name": "first place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-30 15:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-01-30 17:01:00"
  }, {
    "id": "54",
    "name": "second place",
    "startDate": "2015-01-31 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00"

  }, {
    "id": "400",
    "name": "third place",
    "startDate": "2015-02-01 17:01:00",
    "endDate": "2015-02-05 17:01:00"
  }]
}

var phases = arr.places.map(function(e) {
  return [e.name, 50];
});

console.log(phases);
```